# How to stop callback thread in async await method call in C#?

Tags: asynchronous, async-await

I am calling API asynchronously from controller. Sometimes API takes more time to execute and the callback thread trigger another call to API. As a result in total three calls are made to the API. I want to stop second and third call.

How can I stop API being called second and third time?

Below is the code:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> postMessage(WebMailMessagePostRequest postMessageData) {

            UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(_webMailRestClientHelper.domain, _webMailRestClientHelper.useHttps, "address");          
            postMessageData.idImpersonator = SmartType.smartInt(Security.idImpersonatorSession);
            string content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postMessageData);
            byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content);
       _webMailRestClientHelper.PostOrPutServiceAsync<WebMailMessagePostRequest>(Request, uriBuilder.uri, bytes);
}
```

Comment: Tried to call synchronously instead of asynchronously, still the same issue. so not related to sync or async as earlier thought.

Comment: Can you post the code of the calling function.

Comment: The code that I have provided is calling the api from controller. Below is the snippet of the API:  public HttpResponseMessage postMessage(WebMailMessagePostRequest postMessageData) {           
                HttpResponseMessage response = null;.............

Answer (score 0):

If you are using 'async' why are you not awaiting on the API call :

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> postMessage(WebMailMessagePostRequest postMessageData) 
{
                UriBuilder uriBuilder = new UriBuilder(_webMailRestClientHelper.domain, _webMailRestClientHelper.useHttps, "address");          
                postMessageData.idImpersonator = SmartType.smartInt(Security.idImpersonatorSession);
                string content = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postMessageData);
                byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(content);
                response = await   _webMailRestClientHelper.PostOrPutServiceAsync<WebMailMessagePostRequest>(Request, uriBuilder.uri, bytes);
                return response;
}
```

API should also be made async:

```
public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> postMessage(WebMailMessagePostRequest postMessageData) 
{ 
        HttpResponseMessage response = null;

}
```

Comment: my bad I did not provided the latest code. it is already await:return await _webMailRestClientHelper.PostOrPutServiceAsync<WebMailMessagePostRequest>(Request, uriBuilder.uri, bytes);

Comment: I have made the controller method as async because it should not wait for the API to complete its task. There is no need to make API async as it is not waiting for anything. Also as I mentioned earlier even if it is sync at both the place I have the same issue. Don't think is it associated with sync or async approach here